# try except handling in python

Tags: python-2.7, try-except

I have the following code. I want to come out of else block the moment it meets with an exception and I want the for loop to continue. But my code breaks out of the outer for loop as well. Need some help. New to programming.

```
for (....):
   if (....):
       .....
       .....
   else:
       try:
          ....
       except IndexError:
          break
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `break` with a `continue` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Or a `pass` if you want it to keep going inside the `for` but outside the `else`, for your code as it appears, there would be no difference.